# Using time ontology with sensor data

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology

I want to annotate pieces of sensor data (e.g. temperature) with timestamp. I foundout that I can do it using xsd:datetime. However, I also found Time ontology (https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/). What would be a example that using time ontology is much useful than just annotating with xsd:datetime.

Any example please?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I mean, doesn't it depend on what you're planning to do with the data afterwards?

Comment: Yes True, at the moment xsd:datetime is sufficient to do what I want to do (e.g., run SPARQL to retrieve data only for a given date range). But I wonder what can Time ontology do more in sensor data domain. I found one example regarding a calendar/scheduling scenario, where Time ontology can be used to identify (reason) conflicting meeting appointments. but what would be an example scenario in sensor domain ?

Comment: The time Time Ontology seems to specify a lot of fine points and edge cases concerning  intervals and durations. *Consider a simple operation, January 31st + "one month". Should the answer be February 31st (which doesn’t exist)
March 4th (31 days after January 31), or February 28th (assuming its not a leap year)?* (From the documentation of the R package "lubridate" which also handles these datetime semantics. Has nothing to do with OWL but it illustrates one of many problems)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide you an "all done" answer or best way to do something. Sensors data are currently into many research projects and no one can seems to already understand their pros and cons. It is due to the explosion of the *Smart Cities* concept.

Here are some OGC standars to start dealing with sensors data.

[Sensor Observation Service](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sos)

[Semantic Sensor Network Ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-ssn/)

You can also refer to the work of [Herr Kolbe](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=fHuIr30AAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra) and its research team. Those are primarly CityGML oriented.